# Authorization form in react js

Tags: reactjs, authorization, user-registration

```
File UserStore.js

import { makeAutoObservable } from "mobx";

export default class UserStore {
    constructor() {
        this._isAuth = false;
        this._user = {};
        makeAutoObservable(this);
    }

    setIsAuth(bool) {
        this._isAuth = bool;
    }

    setUser(user) {
        this._user = user;
    }

    get isAuth() {
        return this._isAuth;
    }

    get user() {
        return this._user;
    }
}

File Auth.js
import React, {useContext, useState} from 'react';
import { NavLink, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import './../styles/auth.css';
import { LOGIN_ROUTE, REGISTRATION_ROUTE } from '../utils/consts';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react-lite';
import { Context } from '../index';
import { login, registration } from '../http/userApi';

const Auth = observer(() => {

    const {user} = useContext(Context)

    const location = useLocation()
    const isLogin = location.pathname === LOGIN_ROUTE

    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')

    const click = async() => {
    
        try {
            let data;
            if (isLogin) {
                data = await login(email, password);
            } else {
                data = await registration(email, password);
            }
            user.setUser(data)
            user.setIsAuth(true)
      
        } catch (e) {
            alert(e.response.data.message)
        }
    }

    return (
        <section className='section auth'>
            <div className='container auth__wrapper'>
                <div className='card'>
                    <form>
                        <h2>{isLogin ? 'Авторизация' : 'Регистрация'}</h2>
                        <input 
                            type='email' 
                            placeholder='Введите ваш email...'
                            value={email}
                            onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                        />
                        <input 
                            type='password' 
                            placeholder='Введите ваш пароль...'
                            value={password}
                            onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                        />
                        <div className='btnandreg'>
                            {isLogin ? 
                                <div className='text'>
                                    Нет аккаунта? <NavLink className='NavLink underline' to={REGISTRATION_ROUTE}>Зарегистрируйтесь!</NavLink>
                                </div>
                                :
                                <div className='text'>
                                    Есть аккаунт? <NavLink className='NavLink underline' to={LOGIN_ROUTE}>Войдите!</NavLink>
                                </div>
                            }
                            <button onClick={() => click()} className='form__btn'>{isLogin ? 'Войти' : 'Регистрация'}</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    );
});

export default Auth;

File userApi.js

import { $authHost, $host } from "./index";
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';

export const registration = async (email, password) => {
    const {data} = await $host.post('api/user/registration', { email, password, role: 'ADMIN' })
    return jwt_decode(data.token)
}

export const login = async (email, password) => {
    const {data} = await $host.post('api/user/login', { email, password })
    return jwt_decode(data.token)
}

export const check = async () => {
    const response = await $host.post('api/auth/registration')
    return response
}
```

Authorization passes, if in the case of successful authorization write alert(), it works, the problem is that the value of the variable isAuth does not change, and I assume that user.setUser(data) also does not work, but I can not be sure, I need to change the value of the variable isAuth to true, and also triggered user.setUser(data), repeat code runs successfully to this point, the problem is in these two lines or may be in another file`

Comment: you are getting error in ` if (isLogin) {
                data = await login(email, password);
            } else {
                data = await registration(email, password);
            }`  either because of `login` or `registration` function. so try block is failing and your catch block is getting executed

Comment: No, that's the thing, if I write alert('login successful') in place of the variable change everything works fine, the problem is that the variable doesn't change